# Separating multiple images from stdin in Java

Tags: java, graphics, stdin

I want to write a program in Java with support for unix pipeline. The problem is that my input files are images and I need in some way to separate them from one another.

I thought that there is no problem because I can read InputStream using `ImageIO.read()` without reseting position. But it isn't that simple. `ImageIO.read()` closes the stream every time an image is read. So I can't read more than one file from stdin. Do you have some solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

The API for [`read()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read%28java.io.InputStream%29) mentions, "This method *does not* close the provided `InputStream` after the read operation has completed; it is the responsibility of the caller to close the stream, if desired." You might also check the result for `null` and verify that a suitable `ImageReader` is available.